# An `/etc/network/if-up.d` script runs, but doesn't launch GUI apps (e.g. firefox-esr)

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, firefox, gui

I need to start `firefox-esr` once the network is available.

Here's what I've got:

```
sudo tee "/etc/network/if-up.d/upif" > /dev/null << EOFBOOT
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=":0"
if [[ "\$IFACE" = "eth0" || "\$IFACE" = "wlan0" ]]; then
    echo "\$(date) \$IFACE" >> /var/log/upif
    firefox-esr &
fi
EOFBOOT
sudo chmod +x "/etc/network/if-up.d/upif"
```

I am getting the date and the interface name in my log file, which means the script runs, but `firefox-esr` doesn't start.

What I've tried:

- adding [`DISPLAY=":0"`](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090426&p=6861145#post6861145)
- `grep -inR "firefox" /var/log`
- using full path to executable, i.e. `/usr/bin/firefox-esr`
- using `sudo firefox-esr &`
- removing the trailing `&`

Nothing helped. However, if I put `IFACE="eth0"` below the shebang  and then run `sudo /etc/network/if-up.d/upif` manually, that exact script you see above does the job and starts firefox.

I am not sure what's the problem there.

This is `2018-06-27-raspbian-stretch-lite` running Debian 9.4.

P.S. Also I initially had logic checking whether Firefox already runs before attempting to start it, but once I realised Firefox isn't launched at all, I removed it

**UPDATE** Found a similar problem: [Start a GUI in NetworkManager if-up.d script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751961/start-a-gui-in-networkmanager-if-up-d-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network event scripts run as the root user, but your desktop environment probably (hopefully) isn't.

This seems like a problematic approach in general. A few things are missing:

- Firefox should run as your logged in user, not root.
- Firefox needs to be able to authenticate to the X server to connect to it (see `~/.Xauthority` and `man xauth`).
- Firefox's environment needs to be set up to work properly in the desktop session (`HOME`, `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` etc.)

I would suggest trying a different approach, e.g. having the network script communicate network status (via a pipe / temporary file / DBus) to something already running in the user session (launched e.g. from `~/.xinitrc`), which then launches GUI apps as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've managed to make it the initial approach work - turned out to be easier than I thought it would be. I've shared what helped and will mark that as an answer. Upvoted your answer to appreciate the effort and a quick response. Thanks again!

Comment: **UPDATE**: this is what I ended up doing - checking internet availability in a script every minute. Accepting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks to Fadabi Nawi](https://askubuntu.com/a/514449/398665), here's what the answer was:

```
su pi -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/firefox-esr &"
```

Key points:

- su to the actual user you normally use (`pi` in my case)
- pass the display number right there (TODO: [find out the actual display number instead of assuming it's `:0`](https://askubuntu.com/a/514172/398665))
- **important** use the full path to Firefox executable, instead of `firefox-esr`